# python 3 - rounding a Decimal with negative ndigits results in Decimal with scientific notation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I noticed a strange behaviour when using the [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) function with a negative rounding factor (the parameter `ndigits`) and with the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module.

I'm using `Python 3` (specifically `3.6.3`, but I don't know if the specific minor version matters for this case).

With `float` it looks normal:

```
>>> round(10000 / 3, 2)
3333.33
>>> round(10000 / 3, 1)
3333.3
>>> round(10000 / 3, 0)
3333.0
>>> round(10000 / 3, -1)
3330.0
>>> round(10000 / 3, -2)
3300.0
```

With `Decimal` the result is correct, but it changes to scientific notation when using a negative rounding factor:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> round(Decimal('10000') / 3, 2)
Decimal('3333.33')
>>> round(Decimal('10000') / 3, 1)
Decimal('3333.3')
>>> round(Decimal('10000') / 3, 0)
Decimal('3333')
>>> round(Decimal('10000') / 3, -1)
Decimal('3.33E+3')
>>> round(Decimal('10000') / 3, -2)
Decimal('3.3E+3')
```

My quick fix was to add `0` to the result, which restores the notation back to "normal" (non-scientific):

```
>>> round(Decimal('10000') / 3, -1) + 0
Decimal('3330')
>>> round(Decimal('10000') / 3, -2) + 0
Decimal('3300')
```

I don't think this classifies as a bug, because only the notation and not the actual value is affected, but it is strange to me nonetheless.

Does anyone have an idea why I am seeing this behaviour? Do you know if it is intended or a minor bug?

Comment: Scientific notation shows sigfigs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is normal and intended. `Decimal` tracks significant digits, and the Decimal `repr` is intended to preserve significant digits. `Decimal('3.3E+3')` has two significant digits, while `Decimal('3300')` has four.

Comment: After your answer I went looking in the source code of the module, and indeed, the docstring in the method [`Decimal.__round__()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/_pydecimal.py#L1906) has an example for the case I have in my question, confirming that it is intentional.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it